# PyExcel with Flask, updating a record

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use pyexcel to import a spreadsheet but I don't want to add existing records to the table. I'd either like to skip them or, preferably, update them.

I'm currently using the `save_book_to_database()` method with an init function. I'd love to be able to return None from the init function and have `save_book_to_database()` skip the record but that doesn't seem to be working.

Do I just need to hand code record inserts and updates or is there a library to handle that more elegantly?

Here's a snippet:

```
@app.route("/importEvents", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def doEventsImport():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        def init_func(row):
            # see if this is an existing event
            eventKey = row["EventKey"]
            foundEvent = db.session.query(Event).filter_by(EventKey=row['EventKey']).first()
            if foundEvent:
                print 'foundEvent:'
                print foundEvent
                return None

            event = Event(row['EventKey'], row['Name'], row['Description'], row['BeginDate'], row['EndDate'], row['RegBeginDate'], row['RegEndDate'], row['Location'], row['Address1'], row['Address2'], row['City'], row['State'], row['Zip'], row['URL'], row['Email'], row['Phone'])
            return event

        request.save_book_to_database(field_name='file', session=db.session,
                                  tables=[Event],
                                  initializers=[(init_func)])
        return "Saved"
```

Comment: Where does `save_book_to_database` come from?  That's not a normal Flask method ... and what does it do?

Comment: with Flask-excel==0.0.4, you can skip or update a row using your init_func if it return None.